# Empty range between strings representing numbers

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8

Here are two range values.

```
('1'..'10').to_a   => ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
```

but,

```
('2'..'10').to_a  => []
```

Why does the second one return an empty array in ruby 1.8.7?

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that Ruby 1.8 is trying to determine whether `('2'..'10')` is a valid range as part of its analysis of the code, and deciding that it's invalid. `'2'` sorts after `'10'` making the range values backwards.

This is a common problem when people try to sort string values, and they'll encounter it again and again until they learn that trick never works.

Using 1.8.7:

```
('2'..'10').to_a
=> []
('02'..'10').to_a
=> ["02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10"]
```

Or:

```
(2..10).map(&:to_s)
=> ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
```

I'd probably use the last method if I needed compatibility with 1.8 and 1.9+ Rubies.

Answer (score 4):

```
irb(main):001:0> '2' > '10'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> '1'>'10'
=> false
```

Because of the string comparison algorithm, range cannot be created with lower bound bigger than the upper bound.

**ACTUALLY** it works in 1.9.3. Strange.

Comment: couldn't get  "range cannot be created with lower bound bigger than the upper bound". can you explain me little bit?

Comment: Well, Range object is created using two objects as in `(1..5)`, 1 is the lower bound and 5 is an upper bound. Range class uses `succ` method on lower bound until it reaches the upper bound. `succ` method in string returns '10' after '9' in 1.9.3, which does not seem logical to me personally.

Comment: `succ` returns next element in an implied sequence. You don't expect that 5.succ == 4, do you? That is why `(5..1).to_a == []`. Hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

That's not what I'm getting:

```
irb(main):001:0> ('2'..'10').to_a
=> ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
```

Unrelated to the question, though: the correct way is:

```
(2..10).to_a
```

(I am using Ruby 1.9.3)

Comment: If you're stuck using 1.8.7 why not just convert the values to integers? `('2'.to_i..'10'.to_i).to_a`

Answer (score 1):

in ruby2.0.0-p-0 this is what I am getting :

```
["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
```